# Is it possible to compress video in android using opengl?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to compress video in android device without using FFMPEG and MediaCodec, is there any other options available ?

Comment: OpenGL is for drawing pictures. There are some interfaces between OpenGL and  video codecs, but these are there so that you can write the pictures that were drawn using OpenGL into a video stream, or in reverse take the pictures from a video stream and use them to draw things (like the screen on a 3D model of a monitor) with OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks @datenwolf, 
I understand this scenario, but do you have any reference to look into that for better understanding.